# How can I set up Windows Defender in Windows 10 to scan removable devices like in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I used to set up Windows Defender up to Windows 8.1 to automatically scan the **removable devices** (like USB drives) when inserted, like explained [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/131564/how-to-make-windows-8s-built-in-anti-virus-scan-removable-drives/).

I can't find the same options in Windows 10, since when I click the setting button, it opens the Windows Settings at the tab "Update and Security" where there are just a few options.

Is it still possible to set up Windows Defender to automatically scan the removable devices (USB) when inserted?

Answer (score 3):

You are limited to the following currently:

> 1) Open Windows Defender
>
> 2) Plug in the pendrive, etc...
>
> 3) Select Custom Scan
>
> 4) Click Scan Now button
>
> 5) Select Removable Drive
>
> [image]

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_defender-protect_scanning/scan-a-pendrive-or-a-removable-disk-using-windows/94eaf652-9718-4f63-b32d-7ab6cd05ab1c)

If that isn't enough I suggest using one of the many alternatives that exists.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply, but it really doesn't answer my question...

Comment: You asked if it was possible.  My answer indicates, it is not possible, but here are the choices you do have available.